# Facebook JS SDK "feed" pushes window to top with dialog opens

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

when using the FB JS SDK "feed" method... the facebook generated popup placed at the very top of the window and automatically forces to window to be scrolls to the top as well.

if the user is at the bottom of a webpage and "feeds" and opens the dialog box... they will jump to the top of the page... which ruins the experience.

any fixes here?

the issue is NOT an anchor tag with a href="#".  I have tested this.  The issue is when the window is displayed from facebook.

please help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not experienced with feed method, in my apps i have fix text to post, when user click on a certain button.

My javascript code snippet is the following:

```
    function post()
                {
                    FB.api('/me/feed', 'post',
                    {
                        message: 'MESSAGE_TEXT',
                        link:'APPLICATION_LINK',
                        name:'APPLICATION_NAME',
                        picture:'PICTURE_URL',
                        description:'DESCRIPTION_TEXT'
                    }, function(response) {
                        if (!response || response.error) {
//I use javascript here to change the button image, for posting error
                        } else {
//I use javascript here to change the button image, for successfull post
                        }
                    });
                }
```

Maybe not the best solution, but its still working for me, and i don't have any popup window or something like that.

Hope this helps with your problem.